# Why are there some users named userxxxx and I can't view their profile?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, users

I saw some users with `userxxxxx` with some of them blue and grayed out. Why  are some grayed out?

Comment: They are users who've deleted their accounts

Comment: Or users who've had their accounts/profiles deleted for them.